# Real time audio plot

Tags: python, matplotlib, pyqt5, microphone

I am trying to plot microphone speech (real time) with python and matplotlib.

Here is what i have done:

**file:chart_1.py**

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.backends.backend_qt5agg import FigureCanvasQTAgg as FigureCanvas
from matplotlib import dates as mpl_dates
from matplotlib.animation import FuncAnimation
from pydub import AudioSegment
import numpy as np
import datetime

import pyaudio

class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        # constants
        self.CHUNK = int(16384/4)
        self.CHUNK_TIME = 125 #msec
        self.FORMAT = pyaudio.paInt16
        self.CHANNELS = 1
        self.RATE = 32750
        
        self.p = pyaudio.PyAudio()
    
    
        MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
        MainWindow.resize(630, 200)
        sizePolicy = QtWidgets.QSizePolicy(QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Expanding, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Fixed)
        sizePolicy.setHorizontalStretch(0)
        sizePolicy.setVerticalStretch(0)
        sizePolicy.setHeightForWidth(MainWindow.sizePolicy().hasHeightForWidth())
        MainWindow.setSizePolicy(sizePolicy)
        MainWindow.setMinimumSize(QtCore.QSize(0, 200))
        MainWindow.setMaximumSize(QtCore.QSize(16777215, 200))
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        self.verticalLayout = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(self.centralwidget)
        self.verticalLayout.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0)
        self.verticalLayout.setSpacing(0)
        self.verticalLayout.setObjectName("verticalLayout")
        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)
        
        self.chart = Canvas(self)
        self.chart.ax.set_facecolor((1,1,1))
        self.chart.ax.tick_params(labelcolor='white')
        
        self.stream = self.p.open(format=self.FORMAT,channels=self.CHANNELS,rate=self.RATE,input=True,output=True,frames_per_buffer=self.CHUNK)

        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)

    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "Microphone chart"))
        
    def plot_microphone_data(self):
        now = datetime.datetime.now()
        self.x_vals = []
        self.y_vals = []
        while(True):
            data = self.stream.read(self.CHUNK)
            #slice = AudioSegment(data, sample_width=2, frame_rate=self.RATE, channels=1)
            #print(len(slice))
            #print(len(slice.raw_data))
            self.stream.write(data)
            
            audio_data = np.frombuffer(data, np.int16)
            
            self.chart.li.set_xdata(np.arange(len(audio_data)))
            self.chart.li.set_ydata(audio_data)
            
            self.chart.fig.canvas.draw()
            self.chart.fig.canvas.flush_events()
        

class Canvas(FigureCanvas):
    def __init__(self,parent):
        self.fig , self.ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(5,4),dpi=200)
        self.fig.patch.set_facecolor((6/255,21/255,154/255))
        
        self.ax.set_position([0., 0, 1., 0.8])
        self.ax.xaxis.tick_top()
        self.ax.tick_params(color=(1,1,1))
        
        super().__init__(self.fig)
        
        parent.verticalLayout.addWidget(self)
        
        plt.cla()
        
        plt.xticks(fontsize=5)
        self.ax.grid(False)
        
        self.li, = self.ax.plot([], [])
        self.ax.set_xlim(0,1000)
        self.ax.set_ylim(-8000,8000)
        
        self.show()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    MainWindow = QtWidgets.QMainWindow()
    ui = Ui_MainWindow()
    ui.setupUi(MainWindow)
    MainWindow.show()
    ui.plot_microphone_data()
    
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

works well, but it hasn't time in x axis so i have made the file **chart_2.py**

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.backends.backend_qt5agg import FigureCanvasQTAgg as FigureCanvas
from matplotlib import dates as mpl_dates
from matplotlib.animation import FuncAnimation
from pydub import AudioSegment
import numpy as np
import datetime

import pyaudio

class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        # constants
        self.CHUNK = int(16384/4)
        self.CHUNK_TIME = 125 #msec
        self.FORMAT = pyaudio.paInt16
        self.CHANNELS = 1
        self.RATE = 32750
        
        self.TIME_WINDOW = 3000 #display 3 seconds on chart
        
        self.p = pyaudio.PyAudio()
    
    
        MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
        MainWindow.resize(630, 200)
        sizePolicy = QtWidgets.QSizePolicy(QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Expanding, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Fixed)
        sizePolicy.setHorizontalStretch(0)
        sizePolicy.setVerticalStretch(0)
        sizePolicy.setHeightForWidth(MainWindow.sizePolicy().hasHeightForWidth())
        MainWindow.setSizePolicy(sizePolicy)
        MainWindow.setMinimumSize(QtCore.QSize(0, 200))
        MainWindow.setMaximumSize(QtCore.QSize(16777215, 200))
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        self.verticalLayout = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(self.centralwidget)
        self.verticalLayout.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0)
        self.verticalLayout.setSpacing(0)
        self.verticalLayout.setObjectName("verticalLayout")
        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)
        
        self.chart = Canvas(self)
        self.chart.ax.set_facecolor((1,1,1))
        self.chart.ax.tick_params(labelcolor='white')
        
        
        
        self.stream = self.p.open(format=self.FORMAT,channels=self.CHANNELS,rate=self.RATE,input=True,output=True,frames_per_buffer=self.CHUNK,stream_callback=self.microphone_callback)
        self.x_vals = np.array([])
        self.y_vals = np.array([])
        self.now = datetime.datetime.now()
        self.stream.start_stream()

        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)

    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "Microphone chart"))
        
    def microphone_callback(self,in_data, frame_count, time_info, status):
        data = in_data
        #slice = AudioSegment(data, sample_width=2, frame_rate=self.RATE, channels=1)
        #print(len(slice))
        #print(len(slice.raw_data))
        
        
        audio_data = np.frombuffer(data, np.int16)
        time_data = np.array([])
        for i in range(0,len(audio_data)):
            time_data = np.append(time_data, self.now)
            self.now = self.now+datetime.timedelta(milliseconds=self.CHUNK_TIME/len(audio_data))
        
        self.x_vals = np.concatenate((self.x_vals, time_data), axis=0)
        self.y_vals = np.concatenate((self.y_vals, audio_data), axis=0)
        
        if(self.x_vals.size>audio_data.size*(self.TIME_WINDOW/self.CHUNK_TIME)):
            self.x_vals = self.x_vals[audio_data.size:]
            self.y_vals = self.y_vals[audio_data.size:]
        
        self.chart.li.set_xdata(self.x_vals)
        self.chart.li.set_ydata(self.y_vals)
        
        x_ticks = []
        for i in range(0,self.TIME_WINDOW+1,1000):
            tick = self.x_vals[0]+datetime.timedelta(milliseconds=i)
            x_ticks.append(tick)
        plt.xticks(x_ticks)
        self.chart.ax.set_xlim(x_ticks[0],x_ticks[-1])
        
        self.chart.fig.canvas.draw()
        self.chart.fig.canvas.flush_events()
        
        return (data, pyaudio.paContinue)

        

class Canvas(FigureCanvas):
    def __init__(self,parent):
        self.fig , self.ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(5,4),dpi=200)
        self.fig.patch.set_facecolor((6/255,21/255,154/255))
        
        self.ax.set_position([0., 0, 1., 0.8])
        self.ax.xaxis.tick_top()
        self.ax.tick_params(color=(1,1,1))
        
        super().__init__(self.fig)
        
        parent.verticalLayout.addWidget(self)

        self.now = datetime.datetime.now()
        self.chart_stop = self.now+datetime.timedelta(milliseconds=parent.TIME_WINDOW)
        
        plt.cla()
        
        date_format = mpl_dates.DateFormatter("%H:%M:%S")
        plt.gca().xaxis.set_major_formatter(date_format)
        
        plt.xticks(fontsize=5)
        self.ax.grid(False)
        
        self.li, = self.ax.plot([], [])
        
        self.ax.set_ylim(-8000,8000)
        
        x_ticks = []
        for i in range(0,parent.TIME_WINDOW+1,1000):
            tick = self.now+datetime.timedelta(milliseconds=i)
            x_ticks.append(tick)
        plt.xticks(x_ticks)
        self.ax.set_xlim(x_ticks[0],x_ticks[-1])
        
        self.show()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    MainWindow = QtWidgets.QMainWindow()
    ui = Ui_MainWindow()
    ui.setupUi(MainWindow)
    MainWindow.show()   
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Chart 2 has time on upper x axis but it has some delay problems.
Can you please advice me to fix that?

Comment: Using while loops in UI frameworks is almost always a terrible idea, as it makes the interface unresponsive and can lead to crashes. Consider that even if you use a slightly "big" chunk size, the frequency is pretty fast, and if the CPU can't keep up you'll end up with delays (at least, if not even buffer underrun), mostly because the rendering is usually slow and you're asking it to do it more often than required. You must put the stream reading in a separate QThread that sends the data using signals that will *queue* the processing and let the view refresh itself only when it actually can.

Comment: Consider that pyaudio also has the callback interface (which is not blocking), so it's probably better to use that instead. Finally, as probably already told you, you should really stop using modified pyuic files, especially where completely pointless: in the code above you could just subclass QMainWindow and use a standard QWidget as central widget, which would make your code much more cleaner and readable (most importantly, because you could get rid of 20 completely useless lines).

Comment: @musicamante as the edited pyuic5 output, that code is only for minimal reproduce example. Ok I will try the pyaudio callback, but I don't know if only that will fix the delay problems

Comment: Creating a **minimal** example is one more reason for **not** using that: a simple subclassing of QMainWindow or even QWidget would have been better and simpler (and, as said, much more shorter). If you don't use QWidget subclassing because you've the habit of editing pyuic files, then it's just a **bad** habit that has *no benefit* at all. That said, I used pyaudio for playing/recording, it works fine: create a function for the recording callback that emits a custom signal with the *yet unprocessed* data (the basic np decoded array), and connect that signal to the function that appends data.

Comment: Sorry man, I changed the code and now works, but i don't understand clearly about the sub-classing, QMainWindow, QWidget etc. Can you expaing me, or can you provide me some help about? If you want i can post the updated chart_2.py code as an answer.

Comment: Read the guidelines about [using Designer](https://www.riverbankcomputing.com/static/Docs/PyQt5/designer.html) (consider using the multiple inheritance method explained there). If you solved your issue, then you can certainly post your own answer, explaining what you did.